# Alternative to Akka for handling tasks sequentially

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, akka

I have a system which may generate certain events in the lifecycle of a transaction. On every even I need to update a row in a DB and also send out a UI event over websocket.

One option I have is to implement the event processing (DB and UI) in actors thus avoiding any locking issues - also I can afford minor delays so handling this sequentially will greatly simplify matters.

What are alternative ways of handling this in Scala as I feel maybe Actors might be overkill in this case? 
There are those blogs stating that actors should be used for "concurrency with state" - though I would like to see a more appropriate mechanism in order to eliminate this option.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the main unique benefit for using actors is that they are great for encapsulating mutable variables so that you avoid race conditions.

To do what you describe, you could just use classic threads. In your (possibly simplified) description, I don't see the potential for deadlocks. If you want to something a bit more composable, e.g. a sequence of asynchronous tasks, you can use Scala's `Future`s.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all sure if this is applicable for Scala, but there's a great lib for Groovy and Java with several concurrency models. I've myself used the [Dataflow Concurrency](http://www.gpars.org/webapp/quickstart/index.html#__strong_dataflow_concurrency_strong) with great success and can recommend it as a light-weight yet manageable model.

> Dataflow Concurrency offers an alternative concurrency model, which is
>   inherently safe and robust. It puts an emphasis on the data and their
>   flow though your processes instead of the actual processes that
>   manipulate the data. Dataflow algorithms relieve developers from
>   dealing with live-locks, race-conditions and make dead-locks
>   deterministic and thus 100% reproducible. If you don’t get dead-locks
>   in tests you won’t get them in production.

There are other models available in the linked `GPars` library as well.

I wouldn't suggest making the threading yourself, unless you have no other choices.

**Addendum**

After posting I got interested in the topic and made a few searches. Seems like [Akka has direct support for Dataflow model](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/dataflow.html) also. Or at least has had in some version.

Answer (score 0):

Actors avoid locking issues because they use queues to interact. You can use threads with (blocking) queues and get the same level of safety. The only advantage of Actors over Threads is that an Actor does not spend memory for call stack, thus we can have many more actors than threads in the same amount of core memory. The downside of actor model is that a complex algorithm which could be implemented in single thread require several actors and so actor implementation may look obscured.